# How does creating a dynamically allocated string in C work?

Tags: c, string, dynamic-allocation

I don't understand how dynamically allocated strings in C work. Below, I have an example where I think I have created a pointer to a string and allocated it 0 memory, but I'm still able to give it characters. I'm clearly doing something wrong, but what?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
char *str = malloc(0);
int i;
str[i++] = 'a';
str[i++] = 'b';
str[i++] = '\0';
    printf("%s\n", str);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're doing is undefined behavior. It might appear to work now, but is not required to work, and may break if anything changes.

`malloc` normally returns a block of memory of the given size that you can use. In your case, it just so happens that there's valid memory outside of that block that you're touching. That memory is not supposed to be touched; `malloc` might use that memory for internal housekeeping, it might give that memory as the result of some `malloc` call, or something else entirely. Whatever it is, it isn't yours, and touching it produces undefined behavior.

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way to check if I am allocating the correct amount of memory for my strings?

Comment: @dyxh: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking, but if you're asking if there are any tools to debug problems like this, then yes: off the top of my head, there's Valgrind and AddressSanitizer. If you're asking how to allocate the memory correctly, you'll need to pass `malloc` the size of your string, including the trailing NUL byte. If you're asking if you can check in your code whether a block of memory is large enough, there is no standard way; some implementations may offer such functionality, whereas others may not; such functionality is not required.

Answer (score 0):

Section 7.20.3 of the current C standard states in part:

"If the size of the space requested is zero, the behavior is
implementation defined: either a null pointer is returned, or the
behavior is as if the size were some nonzero value, except that the
returned pointer shall not be used to access an object."

This will be implementation defined. Either it could send a NULL pointer or as mentioned something that cannot be referenced

Answer (score 0):

By doing `malloc(0)` you are creating a `NULL` pointer or a unique pointer that can be passed to `free`. Nothing wrong with that line. The problem lies when you perform pointer arithmetic and assign values to memory you have not allocated. Hence:

```
str[i++] = 'a'; // Invalid (undefined).
str[i++] = 'b'; // Invalid (undefined).
str[i++] = '\0'; // Invalid (undefined).

printf("%s\n", str); // Valid, (undefined).
```

It's always good to do two things:

1. Do not `malloc` 0 bytes.
2. Check to ensure the block of memory you `malloc`ed is valid.

... to check to see if a block of memory requested from `malloc` is valid, do the following:

```
if ( str == NULL ) exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
```

... after your call to `malloc`.

Answer (score 0):

Your are overwriting non-allocated memory. This might looks like working. But you are in trouble when you call `free` where the heap function tries to gives the memory block back.

Each `malloc()` returned chunk of memory has a header and a trailer. These structures hold at least the size of the allocated memory. Sometimes yout have additional guards. You are overwriting this heap internal structures. That's the reason why `free()` will complain or crash.

So you have an undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Your malloc(0) is wrong. As other people have pointed out that may or may not end up allocating a bit of memory, but regardless of what malloc actually does with 0 you should in this trivial example allocate at least 3*sizeof(char) bytes of memory.

So here we have a right nuisance. Say you allocated 20 bytes for your string, and then filled it with 19 characters and a null, thus filling the memory. So far so good. However, consider the case where you then want to add more characters to the string; you can't just out them in place because you had allocated only 20 bytes and you had already used them. All you can do is allocate a whole new buffer (say, 40 bytes), copy the original 19 characters into it, then add the new characters on the end and then free the original 20 bytes. Sounds inefficient doesn't it. And it is inefficient, it's a whole lot of work to allocate memory, and sounds like an specially large amount of work compared to other languages (eg C++) where you just concatenate strings with nothing more than str1 + str2.

Except that underneath the hood those languages are having to do exactly the same thing of allocating more memory and copying existing data. If one cares about high performance C makes it clearer where you are spending time, whereas the likes of C++, Java, C# hide the costly operations from you behind convenient-to-use classes. Those classes can be quite clever (eg allocating more memory than strictly necessary just in case), but you do have to be on the ball if you're interested in extracting the very best performance from your hardware.

This sort of problem is what lies behind the difficulties that operations like Facebook and Twitter had in growing their services. Sooner or later those convenient but inefficient class methods add up to something unsustainable.